# How can I get the code coverage in meteor.js?

Tags: meteor, code-coverage, velocity

I am using velocity html reporter and console reporter to find the test report. But I am unable to find the code coverage.
Is there any way to see the code coverage?

Answer (score -1):

> npm run coverage:watch

Works perfectly well for us, is amazingly fast and provides you with a nicely formatted HTML report.

Comment: this is just a custom script